# Reload required when updating an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

When updating my extension, users always have to reload the extension. Is it because the extension is activated when the users are doing this? Is it possible to make it so that users don't have to reload the extension when updating it?

My extension contribution points in case that helps:

- languages
- grammars
- configuration
- configurationDefaults
- configurationSnippets
- debuggers

Comment: Maybe if the extension is already activated it requires a reload of VSC

Comment: I see that some extensions never require a reload when they get updated. Does this just mean that they don't get activated at the upgrading time?

Comment: If an extension is activated it uses some resources and maybe it is difficult to remove it completely or the `deactivate()` does not release all. You don't need to reload, you get the update when you switch workspaces or the next time you start VSC

Comment: This started happening to me recently, I'm sure extensions used to just update behind the scenes previously. Now the extensions icon gets a notification dot and I have to hit 'reload' .... is there some way to go back to how it was, and just have them auto-update ?